# Convert Timestamp string (dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss) to Date (DD/MM/YY) in Google Sheets

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with a column populated with a DateTime (unfortunately missing the leading 0 in the case of single-digit dates).

For example:

- 1 Apr 2021, 00:01:11
- 31 Mar 2021, 22:12:43

I want to convert these to the following format:

- 01/04/2021
- 31/03/2021

I have tried:

```
=DATE(MID(C2,7,4), MONTH(MID(C2, 3, 3)&1), REGEXEXTRACT(C2, "\d+"))
```

And while that works fine for the single digits, it's causing an error when double-digit days come up (should have said, I want this to work in an arrayformula really, or at least have one formula I can copy down the 21k rows)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C, ","),,1), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

[image]